# How do I remove error bars from legend (matplotlib)?

Tags: graph, matplotlib, legend

I am plotting 4 sets of data on the same graph, each set has different y values depending on some variable P. In the legend I end up with 8 different element, 4 for each different set of data and 4 for the error bars, as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zOVm.png

A simplified version of the code is shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x1, y1, c='b', marker='o', label='P=0', markersize=4)
plt.plot(x2, y2, c='g', marker='+', label='P=1', markersize=4)
plt.plot(x3, y3, c='r', marker='*', label='P=2', markersize=4)
plt.plot(x4, y4, c='k', marker='s', label='P=3', markersize=4)
plt.errorbar(x1, y1, yerr=yerr0, color='b')
plt.errorbar(x2, y2, yerr=yerr1, color='g')
plt.errorbar(x3, y3, yerr=yerr2, color='r')
plt.errorbar(x4, y4, yerr=yerr3, color='k')
plt.ylabel("Different y")
plt.xlabel("Different x")
plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=MaxX)
plt.suptitle("Different y vs Different x", fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', numpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

I only want the markers for the data in the legend, how do I remove the ones for the error bars?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign your lines to variables when you create them you can tell `.legend()` which lines to show:

```
line1, = plt.plot(x1, y1, c='b', marker='o', label='P=0', markersize=4)
line2, = ...
line3, = ...
line4, = ...
```

And then draw the legend with:

```
plt.legend((line1, line2, line3, line4), loc='upper right', numpoints=1)
```

And to change the labels for each line you can also pass the tuple with the new labels:

```
plt.legend((line1, line2, line3, line4), ('label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4'), loc='upper right', numpoints=1)
```

Hopefully this will give what you want.

Comment: I tried this earlier and had the problem where, next to the label for each line, it would write 2DLine(P=0) etc, like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TDByc.png

Comment: You can also pass the new labels to `.ledend()`. see updated answer. Since you didn't include a fully reproducible code it is difficult to say what else is going wrong...

Comment: Brilliant, this has solved the problem!! I tried something similar before I posted the problem but that didn't work and I couldn't solve it. Thanks!